# Event when paint complete or smth similar in wxFrame

Tags: wxwidgets

Is there in wxFrame such event, when frame fully painted, so I can query data while interface is done?
Now I quering some data in ***Application::OnInit()*** function right before ***return true*** and interface not painting while data is quering. Looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly are you trying to do here, but you might be interested in [CallAfter()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_evt_handler.html#a63c7351618fd77330d80a250b3719519)

Comment: Now interface not fully loaded (only frame with placeholders for images and text) while data is loading from remote server. When it done loading images appear in the frame layout.

Comment: Sorry, I have really no idea what is this comment about.

Comment: When I start application, there atre three visible things happens: 1. Main frame appears witout any visible elements (like images or text), 2. Application does some job (retrieve data from server). 3. Layout of main frame appears fully appears. Second step can take up to 2 second

Comment: I'm still not sure what the question is, but clearly, if you want to avoid blocking the GUI for these 2 seconds, you need to extract step (2) in its own thread.